# Can you conditionally trigger an azure function based on an event hub message header property?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an azure node.js function that uses an eventHubTrigger that listens to an event producer topic. As an example, the event hub message has a header property of type X, Y, or Z. Is it possible to add some conditional logic in the function input binding to only trigger the function if the message header property is type X? I would like to avoid having the function trigger on every type and doing the filtering in the function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to filter.  Each event that is published to a partition in your Event Hub will be surfaced to your Function; any decision to ignore data rather than process it must happen your code.